# Updating drupal/core using composer: "[RuntimeException] Could not delete web/core" (using Lando)

Tags: 8, composer

Trying to update Drupal 8 core.

```
composer require drupal/core:~8.9.2 --no-update
```

This works fine.

```
composer -vvv update
```

It fails with the following:

```
  - Updating drupal/core (8.8.5 => 8.9.2):     Update failed (Could not delete web/core: )
Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing drupal/core (8.8.5)

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete web/core:
```

What's the easiest and/or correct way to resolve this?

(This has happened to me before but can't remember what I did to fix it)

Answer (score 1):

OK - so composer does not have read/write access to the folder. I've also seen some people mentioning composer timeouts being the problem.

In my case I am using [Lando](https://lando.dev/) for my dev environment ands listed `web/core` as one of the excludes:

```
excludes:
  - web/core
```

This meant the core files were not available to the container. If I remove core from the excludes then it works fine.